# Problema al desestructurar un objeto "hospital" para obtener la _id

Tags: angular, typescript

Buenas tengo un problema al querer obtener la _id de un hospital al realizar la desestructuracion bien este es el codigo

```
cargarMedico(id: string) {

    this.medicoService.obtenerMedicoPorId(id)
      .subscribe(medico => {
        console.log(medico)
        const { nombre, email, hospital } = medico;
        console.log(nombre, email, hospital)
        this.medicoSeleccionado = medico;
      })

  }
```

Yo si ejecuto en la consola obtengo el hospital completo adjunto foto

[image: Foto de la consola del front]

el problema radica que cuando intento desesctructurar hospital para obtener la _id

```
cargarMedico(id: string) {

    this.medicoService.obtenerMedicoPorId(id)
      .subscribe(medico => {
        console.log(medico)
        const { nombre, email, hospital:{_id} } = medico;
        console.log(nombre, email, hospital)
        this.medicoSeleccionado = medico;
      })

  }
```

Me dice lo siguiente:

```
const _id: any
La propiedad '_id' no existe en el tipo 'Hospital | undefined'.
```

Adjunto el codigo de obtenerMedicoPorId()

```
      obtenerMedicoPorId(id: string) {

    const url = `${base_url}/medicos/${id}`;
    return this.http.get<MedicoInterface>(url, this.headers)
      .pipe(
        map((resp: MedicoInterface) => resp.medico)
      );
  }
```

Adjunto el codigo de MedicoInterface

```
    export interface MedicoInterface {

    ok: boolean;
    medico: Medico;
    uid: string;

}
```

la clase Medico

```
    export class Medico {

    constructor(
        public nombre: string,
        public img: string,
        public email: string,
        public _id: string,
        public usuario?: _MedicoUser,
        public hospital?: Hospital

    ) { }
}
```

Y la clase Hospital

```
export class Hospital {

    constructor(
        public nombre: string,
        public img: string,
        public _id: string,
        public usuario?: _HospitalUser,

    ) { }
}
```

Actualizacion de ERROR

Buenas acabo de hacer unos cambios en el codigo y consegui actualizar y desestructurar para sacar la ID del hospital gracias a esto

```
  cargarMedico(id: string) {

this.medicoService.obtenerMedicoPorId(id)
  .subscribe(medico => {
    console.log(medico)
    const hospital = medico.hospital?._id;
    console.log(hospital)
   
    const { nombre, email } = medico;
    console.log(nombre, email, hospital)
    this.medicoSeleccionado = medico;
    this.medicoForm.setValue({ nombre, email, hospital });
  });
```

}

y ya consigo sacar lo que queria el problema surge cuando lanzo la guardarMedico()

```
guardarMedico() {

    const { nombre } = this.medicoForm.value

    if (this.medicoSeleccionado) {
      //actualizar
      const data = {
        ...this.medicoForm,
        _id: this.medicoSeleccionado.hospital
      }
      this.medicoService.actualizarMedico(data)
        .subscribe(resp => {
          console.log(resp);
          Swal.fire('Actualizado', `${nombre} actualizado correctamente`, 'success');

        })

    } else {
      //crear
      const { nombre } = this.medicoForm.value
      console.log(this.medicoForm.value)
      this.medicoService.crearMedico(this.medicoForm.value)
        .subscribe((resp: any) => {
          console.log(resp);
          Swal.fire('Creado', `${nombre} registrado correctamente`, 'success');
          this.router.navigateByUrl(`/dashboard/medico/${resp.medico._id}`)
        })
    }


  }
```

Que me salta este error pero es extraño porque yo le estoy mandado los String ya de el nombre el email y la id del hospital

[image: Error de consola Type JSON]

Answer (score 0):

Asumiendo que la respuesta de tu método "cargarMedico" te devuelve un objeto de tipo "Medico" puedes hacer lo siguiente

```
cargarMedico(id: string) {

    this.medicoService.obtenerMedicoPorId(id)
      .subscribe(response => {
        console.log(medico)
        const medico: Medico = response;
        console.log(medico, medico.hospital._id)
        this.medicoSeleccionado = medico;
      })
  }
```